Adding custom translation in Django GeoNode
How can I add a new language for GeoNode mapstore client?
I've created a translation file in /django_geonode_mapstore_client/geonode_mapstore_client/static/mapstore/ms-translations, but it doesn't work.
By the way, the localization of GeoNode seems very confusing. There's the translation for my language in the main GeoNode repository, but it only applies to a small subset of the site, backend-generated parts, as I see. The main part of the site is frontend geonode_mapstore_client, which misses the needed translation. Also, although geonode_mapstore_client has many language files, settings just use five.
